# Passing touch events to UIViewController's view

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiwindow

I'm trying to have my iPad app mirror the app's screen to a secondary screen via a VGA cable.  Due to performance issues, I only want to have my view's displayed on the secondary screen, but still capture touch events via the iPad's screen.

My current method is with two UIWindows: one for the VGA-connected screen that shows all the views, animations etc. and another UIWindow for the iPad screen which captures touch events.  This works great performance-wise and I can log the touch events received on the iPad screen.

But for some reason I cannot pass the `touchesBegan:`, `touchesEnded:` etc methods to my `UIViewControllers` and have them react correctly.  If I send it straight to the `UIViewController` I can capture them by overriding the touch events on the `UIViewController` but that's only useful for capturing touches on the background, not for buttons etc that are added to the `UIViewController`.

Then I tried sending the touch events to `viewController.view` and they disappear somewhere else.  I even tried looping through each subview in the view controller and still no dice.

I must be missing something simple, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had this problem too. Your problem can be solved very simply.
You can just overwrite the UIView's hitTest method, like this:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
  return [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] secondWindow] hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

and you can pass the touch event to the other view.
My problem is harder than yours. I want to "copy" the event, not only "passing" it.  Does any one know how to do this?